# What does the -fs flag do in the ln command?

Tags: options, ln

came across this line in a code base today `ln -fs /tmp/Cargo.lock .` and I couldn't find the `-fs` argument anywhere in `man ln`. What does it do?

P.S. The project runs this command inside of a docker container

I tried this command on my local machine too by making a file in the same directory path as the given command and it ran.

Comment: There are two options(`-f` and `-s`), and they are explained in the `ln(1)` manpage.

Comment: so can they be used together as one flag `-fs`?

Comment: Yes, single letter flags without arguments can be combined. `ln -f -s` is the same as `ln -sf` or `ln -fs`.

Comment: Note that this is often the case with Linux tools because the [GNU coding standards](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Command_002dLine-Interfaces) recommend using the `getopt()` function to parse command-line options, which is written to handle single-letter options that way.  So as @mosvy wrote, if you encounter an option you have not seen in the manpage, checking if it is a concatenation of single-letter options will often get you there (although you should not rely on it when formulating you own command-line, as programmers may still choose to do things "their way ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard Unix tools, and tools using the standard way of parsing command line options, allow for combining multiple single letter options into a single string of options (as long as the individual options don't take option-arguments)<sup>1</sup>.

Because of the way the `-f` and `-s` options to the `ln` utility are defined (as options that don't take arguments), the command `ln -fs` is  the same as `ln -f -s`.

The `-f` and the `-s` options to the `ln` utility are described separately in the `ln(1)` manual (see `man ln`), but in short they are

> `-f`
>       Force existing destination pathnames to be removed to allow the link.
>
> `-s`
>       Create symbolic links instead of hard links.

(The above was taken from [the POSIX specification for `ln`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ln.html))

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>This is a POSIX guideline for command line utilities.  See "Guideline 14" in [Utility Syntax Guidelines](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02).</sub>